# Java servlet upload file to "Web Pages" folder

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I am making simple upload servlet.

My code is:

```
    private final int FILE_LENGHT = 150;
    private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/img/";
.
.
.
.
.

    @Override
    public void uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //process only if its multipart content
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            try {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                        new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        File f = new File(item.getName());
                        String ex = suo.getFileExtension(f);
                        String name = suo.randomString(FILE_LENGHT) + "." + ex;
                        item.write(new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                    }
                }

                //File uploaded successfully
                request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
            }

        } else {
            request.setAttribute("message",
                    "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
        }
    }
```

I try to upload img to `WEB-PAGES` folder. It is possible?

Structure of this folder is:

```
Web Pages
         WEB-INF
         img
         upload.jsp
```

But i get allways exeption:

```
File Upload Failed due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
The system can not find the path
```

The code it works for path `C:\uploadFolder` but not for upload to `Web Pages` folder.

Why?

Comment: You want to upload *into your webapplication* so that you can download that file again? For some ServletEngines  servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") resolves to a "real" filesystem path (if app was deployed exploded and so on...)

Comment: @Jan Thank you, it work!

Comment: Its not ideal to store images in your webapp itself..instead just use a particular location outside of your webapp keep it configurable.

Comment: The points is only part of the deal - by accepting an answer you mark that issue "done" in a way, so others willing to help would not be drawn into reading and understanding your question, then reading all the comments only to find out after that, that it's already been taken care of. But the points are nice nonetheless. With now 17 you can even upvote answers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to upload into your webapplication so that you can download that file again? For some ServletEngines

```
servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
```

resolves to a "real" filesystem path (if app was deployed exploded and so on...)